# Retrieving a Facebook User Friends List using Auth0 and Aurelia

Tags: facebook-graph-api, aurelia, auth0

I am using Auth0 for user authentication in my Aurelia Single Page App. I can successfully sign in and out using the code below in my app.js

```
login() {
  this.lock.show();   
}
```

And in the constructor:

```
this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
     self.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        self.isAuthenticated = true;
        self.lock.hide();
    });
}
```

I wish to now make a call to the Facebook Graph API and retrieve a list of the logged in user's friends. I have already set the permission to grant access to the app for this function. I am trying to get the list of friends using this the fetch moduke like:

```
this.http.fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{user-id}/friends', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authResult.idToken
    }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(friends => this.friends = friends);
```

However I am receiving an error "An access token is required to request this resource". I do not know if I am doing this properly. I have read the docs but I am stuck. I will really appreciate any help offered. Thanks guys!

Comment: You need to pass the access token with your API call, what is unclear about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the Facebook API with an access token issued by Facebook instead of the Auth0 `id_token` issued as part of the authentication process.

> Identity Provider **(in this case Facebook)** access tokens can be obtained after the user has authenticated with the IdP by making an HTTP GET call to the `/api/v2/user/{user-id}` endpoint containing an Auth0 API token generated with `read:user_idp_tokens` scope.

For more information about this see the topic on [Identity Provider Access Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/idp) in the existing documentation. That page also links to a ste-by-step tutorial on how to [Call an Identity Provider API](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/calling-an-external-idp-api).